# Python Subprocess - understanding of arguments

Tags: python, subprocess

I am currently re-working a file that uses the Subprocess module of python.
The lines starting the proccesses are the following:

```
cmd = ["/usr/bin/time", '-f', '%e %M %P', '-o', time_file, script] 
p = subprocess.Popen(cmd, stdout=subprocess.PIPE, stderr=subprocess.PIPE)
```

In the first line the `time_file` and `script` are a file to temporarily store runtime infos (such as used ram, cpu, etc.) and the script to run, repectively.

But I don't understand the first arguments in the list (`"/usr/bin/time", '-f', '%e %M %P', '-o'`).

Anyone can help me decipher, or point me to a piece of doc that can help me understand what are those arguments, and how to create my own list of arguments?

Answer (score 1):

The first argument `/usr/bin/time` is the name of the program which is run in the subprocess, and the subsequent elements in the `cmd` list are the arguments for that program. You can learn more about its usage by typing `man time` in your shell, or by visiting the [documentation](https://linux.die.net/man/1/time).

You can also learn more about the Popen object and the subprocess module [here](https://docs.python.org/3/library/subprocess.html#subprocess.Popen).